# Output elements in array using perl

Tags: perl

I have an array like this:

```
my @array = qw( zero one two three four five six seven eigth nine);
```

How to output a subarray consisting of strings of length 4 from @array. For example, if the string is equal to 4, the new array will be output as `@subarray = ( zero four five nine )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in function [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) serves as the "filter" operation in Perl, capable of filtering a list based on a regular expression or an arbitrary block.

If given a block, `grep` will call the block for each element of the list, setting the implicit variable `$_` to the current value. It will keep the values which return truthy. So your filter would look like

```
my @subarray = grep { length == 4 } @array;
```

`length`, like a lot of built-in Perl functions, can take an argument (`length($a)`, etc.), but when called without one it automatically takes the implicit variable `$_` as an argument.

You can also pass it a regular expression. This is mainly useful if you're worried your coworkers like you too much and want to make some enemies.

```
my @subarray = grep(/^.{4}$/, @array);
```

Comment: So `length` is like querying of what?

Comment: length with no argument uses $_as a default argument

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions See [`$_` in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_) for a long list of things that take `$_` as their default